# Add an image to Drupal 7 using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm migrating data from Zoho creator into Drupal 7. I wrote a PHP script to get all records and save them into nodes and that worked fine, but I need help to get the images and add them to the nodes as well. This is the code I have to get the image using CURL:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_URL => $url.$id."/Image1/download",
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken $token")
));
$image = curl_exec($curl);
```

What should I do after that?

Comment: Solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save as file your data using [`file_save_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_data/7.x)

```
$image = curl_exec($curl);

// save as file in Drupal
$file = file_save_data($image);

var_dump($file->fid);
```

Then, to use as image you could use [`image_style_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/image_style_url/7.x) :

```
$imgfile = file_load($fid);
$url = image_style_url("thumb", $imgfile->uri);
```